# Semop returns identifier removed

Tags: c, multiprocessing, ipc, semaphore

I am creating a multi-process application with a shared memory segment and a semaphore locking it and signal handlers.

Whenever I lock and unlock my semaphore everything is ok, as long as it is in my main program (or one of the children).

The problem occurs when I am inside a signal handler. There I lock the semaphore, do some updates on the shared memory segment and unlock it.

I have a `struct sembuf` let's call it `sb`.

My lock code

```
void semLock(){
  sb.sem_op=-1;
  semop(sID,sb,sizeof(sb);
}
```

my unlock code

```
void semUnlock(){
  sb.sem_op=1;
  semop(sID,sb,sizeof(sb);
}
```

and how I do my stuff

```
void signalHandler(int segnum){
  semLock();
  //do some stuff
  semUnlock();
}
```

There is no real reason why this would not work as `sID` is global and is inherited to all the children the parent process creates and also when the children are running other code that locks and unlocks the semaphore.

I think the issue is that this is inside a signal handler but I do not understand why.
The error that is printed in the terminal is

```
semop failed identifier removed
```

I try googling the error but did not find any meaningful or relevant information on what might cause it.

**EDIT**
when I create `sb` it's initialized with `{0,-1,0}`
I only have one semaphore in my ipcs

Comment: Why don't you use mutex?

Comment: @NTN I never saw them before but it is part of an University assignment so we have to use what we are taught.

Comment: Read this http://koti.mbnet.fi/niclasw/MutexSemaphore.html

Comment: Well yeah they might be better but I am not allowed to use them as it's part of a university assignment

Comment: and the semaphore's initial value is 1 so more or less it's the same

Comment: In your code, in semLock(), you need to check the value of sb.sem_op to know whether it is already locked and iff it is not locked then only lock it.  In signalHandler(), do your task iff semLock() succeed, otherwise wait and try again. I hope this will help

Comment: @NTN Isn't that done automatically (waiting locking etc?) that's the point of using semaphores and not integers

Comment: here is the thing, from what I know running sem_op will actually get blocked if the semaphore is locked
I think the whole waiting and checking thing is done on it's own

Comment: You didn't specify 'sp.sem_num' which is semaphore index in array, You passed 'sizeof(sb)' instead os '1' if I am not wrong, and semop() need one more ')'. Check the return value of semop().

Comment: ah sorry, I forgot to add that information, let me edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out somewhere in my code I was losing the semaphore ID and semLock and semUnlock were trying to lock and unlock a wrong ID and they were returning an error